# Electron, React and electron-redux - Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, electron

I have an electron app created with electron-forge trying to utilize  electron-redux v1.5.4. I'm also using @reduxjs/toolkit

I have implented my mainRenderer and storeRenderer in the manner described in the electron-redux readme file([here](https://github.com/klarna/electron-redux)), adjusted for @reduxjs/toolkit

mainStore.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import appReducer from "./appSlice";
import {
  forwardToRenderer,
  triggerAlias,
  replayActionMain,
} from "electron-redux";

const configureMainStore = () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer:  appReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(forwardToRenderer),
  });

  replayActionMain(store);

  return store;
};

export default configureMainStore;
```

rendererStore.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import appReducer from './appSlice';
import { forwardToMain, replayActionRenderer, getInitialStateRenderer  } from 'electron-redux';

const configureRendererStore = () => {
  const initialState = getInitialStateRenderer();

  const defaultMiddleWare = get

  const store = configureStore({
      reducer: appReducer ,
      initialState: initialState,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().unshift(forwardToMain)
    });

  replayActionRenderer(store);

  return store;
}

export default configureRendererStore;
```

When I run compiling the Renderer Code I get the following error:
**`ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\MyDev\AirFarmer\node_modules\electron'`**

The chrome window gives a bit more detail:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js?bdb9:1)
    at eval (index.js?bdb9:1)
    at Object../node_modules/electron/index.js (index.js:2259)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:4332)
    at fn (index.js:4543)
    at eval (forwardToMain.js?74c1:8)
    at Object../node_modules/electron-redux/dist/middleware/forwardToMain.js (index.js:2216)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:4332)
    at fn (index.js:4543)
    at eval (index.js?78f6:71)
```

I've read this is related to webpack v5+

had a similar issue with "path" which I was able to solve with by updating the webpack.render.config:

```
module.exports = {
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    },
  }
};
```

I've tried lots of things already including setting `nodeIntegration: true` in webPreferences when creating the browser window.

I have tried adding `fs:false` as fallback in my webpack config. This fails because one of the electron-redux files(or its dependencies) uses it.

Has anybody else experienced this? Does anybody have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a repo to share, most probably this is solvable by properly exposing fs to the frontend. However, you could also write a backend function which you call then via `ipcRenderer.invoke`

Comment: my suggestion, follow electron tutorial, and then add react to it, or use a electron/react boilerplate, https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate then you can add redux.